# Jquery popup with light box effect

Tags: jquery

From where i get the light box popup script.

similar to the 'book travel' on the left side of the site 
http://www.ifly.com/

Comment: Thanks every one for your valuable comments.But i got another  solution, by adding a div after the search section with setting z-index for each section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Block UI plugin
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Answer (score 0):

May be this

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/